# Javascript, implementing custom Object.Create

Tags: javascript, tree, prototype

I need to implement inheritance tree in JavaScript where each node can have more than 1 parent. We have to implement `Object.Create` and `Object.call` methods on our own. We are specifically not allowed to use `new` keyword. Here is what I have so far:

```
    var myObject = {
    hash:0,
    parents: [],
    create: function(args){
        //TODO check if not circular
        if(args instanceof Array){
            for(i=0;i<args.length;i++){
                this.parents.push(args[i]);                
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    call : function(fun,args){
        //TODO: dfs through parents
        return this[fun].apply(this,args); 
    },   
}

var obj0 = myObject.create(null);
obj0.func = function(arg) { return "func0: " + arg; };
var obj1 = myObject.create([obj0]);
var obj2 = myObject.create([]);
obj2.func = function(arg) { return "func2: " + arg; };
var obj3 = myObject.create([obj1, obj2]);

var result = obj0.call("func", ["hello"]);
alert(result);
//calls the function of obj2 istead of obj0
```

The problem with this code is that I get a call to obj2's function instead of obj0's. I'm suspecting that `create()` function should not return `this`, but something else instead (create instance of itself somehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current solution, you are not actually creating a new object with your `myObject.create()` function, you are just using the same existing object and resetting it's parent array. Then, when you define `.func()` you are overriding that value, which is why `func2:` appears in your alert.

What you need to do is actually return a brand new object. returning `this` in your `myObject.create()` will just return your existing object, which is why things are getting overridden.

To avoid using the new keyword, you'll want to do either functional inheritance or prototypal inheritance. The following solution is functional inheritance:

```
function myObject (possibleParents) {

  //create a new node
  var node = {};

  //set it's parents
  node.parents = [];

  //populate it's parents if passed in
  if (possibleParents) {
    if (possibleParents instanceof Array) {
      for (var index = 0; index < possibleParents.length; index++) {
        node.parents.push(possibleParents[index]);
      }
    } else {
      node.parents.push(possibleParents);
    };
  }

  //
  node.call = function(fun,args) {
      return this[fun].apply(this,args); 
  };

  return node;
};

var obj0 = myObject();
obj0.func = function(arg) { return "func0: " + arg; };
var obj1 = myObject([obj0]);
var obj2 = myObject();
obj2.func = function(arg) { return "func2: " + arg; };
var obj3 = myObject([obj1, obj2]);

var result = obj0.call("func", ["hello"]);
alert(result); // this will successfully call "func0: " + arg since you created a new object
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed fix this problem only by using function instead of variable.

```
function myObject () {
    this.parents = [];
    this.setParents = function(parents){
        if(parents instanceof Array){
            for(i=0;i<parents.length;i++){
                this.parents.push(parents[i]);                
            }
        }
    };
    this.call = function(fun,args) {
        return this[fun].apply(this,args); 
    };   
}

var obj0 = new myObject();
obj0.func = function(arg) { return "func0: " + arg; };
var obj2 = new myObject();
obj2.func = function(arg) { return "func2: " + arg; };

var result = obj0.call("func", ["hello"]);
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I get around without using **new** keyword?

Comment: myObject.create = function () {return new myObject()};

var obj0 = myObject.create();

Comment: I thing something like this

Comment: But it is still using new keyword :S. If I'm not going to get any more answers I'll mark yours as correct, it might help someone else :)